# Data Class Validations not working in Micronaut

Tags: kotlin, micronaut-data, javax-validation

Context:
I'm using micronaut version 3.4.2 and Kotlin 1.7.22.
I have a Data class in another project which I download as a dependency Jar. The javax field validations are not working in the controller layer.

My data Class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class ItemsTO(
    @field:Min(value = 1, message = "Minimum quantity has to be 1") val quantity: Int
)

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class RequestTO(
    val items: List<ItemsTO>
)
```

My Controller:

```
@Post("/")
@Status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
fun handleRequest(@Valid @Body requestTO: RequestTO): ResponseTO {}
```

Reading the documentation I saw that `@Introspected` is required. I added that annotation as well as `@Validated` on the controller but it's still doesn't validate the request body; the request goes through. I saw in some other projects where this is implemented and they don't use @Introspected or @Validated annotations.

In the project having the controller(where the data class containing module is imported) I have these in my build.gradle

```
implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
kapt "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java"
kapt "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
```

I'm not able to figure out what the issue is and why the fields in the request body are not being validated

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
In my code I have two data classes. The validation message I'm expecting is from the data class{`ItemsTO`) used as a type in another data class(`RequestTO`) field `items`. Now the request body will be of type `RequestTO` hence for the validation on `ItemsTO` to work we need the request body class to be:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class RequestTO(
    @field:@Valid val items: List<ItemsTO>
)
```

We have to add `@field:@Valid` on the field whose data class is getting validated.

ref: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/valid-spring-annotation#4-validating-nested-objects